# Double Buffering with Java Swing leaving a trail

Tags: java, swing

The project I am working on is intended to show a moveable `.gif` with a background behind it. Currently if I use `super.paint(g);` then the character and the background painted flicker. If I don't, then it leaves a trail like the image included. I have no idea why this is happening and need help.

[image: image animation with java swing]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class keyboardinput extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private JPanel contentPane;

    private Image playerModelRight;
    private Image playerModelLeft;
    private Image playerModelAttackRight;
    private Image playerModelAttackLeft;
    private Image playerModelStandRight;
    private Image playerModelStandLeft;
    private Image background;
    private Image doubleBuffer;

    private int direction;

    private Timer timer;

    private boolean up;
    private boolean down;
    private boolean left;
    private boolean right;
    private boolean attack;

    private int x, y;
    private int speed = 4;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    keyboardinput frame = new keyboardinput();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public keyboardinput() {

        super("Keyboard input testing");

        x = 200;
        y = 200;

        ImageIcon playerModelIconRight = new    ImageIcon(keyboardinput.class.getResource("/images/bitdashright.gif"));
        playerModelRight = playerModelIconRight.getImage();

        ImageIcon playerModelIconLeft = new ImageIcon(keyboardinput.class.getResource("/images/bitdashleft.gif"));
        playerModelLeft = playerModelIconLeft.getImage();

        ImageIcon playerModelIconStandRight = new ImageIcon(keyboardinput.class.getResource("/images/bitdashstandright.gif"));
        playerModelStandRight = playerModelIconStandRight.getImage();

        ImageIcon playerModelIconStandLeft = new ImageIcon(keyboardinput.class.getResource("/images/bitdashstandleft.gif"));
        playerModelStandLeft = playerModelIconStandLeft.getImage();

        ImageIcon playerModelIconAttackRight = new ImageIcon(keyboardinput.class.getResource("/images/bitdashattackright.gif"));
        playerModelAttackRight = playerModelIconAttackRight.getImage();

        ImageIcon playerModelIconAttackLeft = new ImageIcon(keyboardinput.class.getResource("/images/bitdashattackleft.gif"));
        playerModelAttackLeft = playerModelIconAttackLeft.getImage();

        ImageIcon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon(keyboardinput.class.getResource("/images/backgroundtest.png"));
        background = backgroundIcon.getImage();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(50, 50, 800, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();

        addKeyListener(this);

        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        Dimension size = getSize();
        if (doubleBuffer == null || doubleBuffer.getWidth(this) != size.width || doubleBuffer.getHeight(this) != size.height) {
            doubleBuffer = createImage(size.width, size.height);
        }

        if (doubleBuffer != null) {
            Graphics g2 = doubleBuffer.getGraphics();
            paint(g2);
            g2.dispose();

            g.drawImage(doubleBuffer, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            paint(g);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        if (attack) {
            if (direction == 1)
                g.drawImage(playerModelAttackRight, x, y, this);
            if (direction == 0) {
                x -= 15;
                g.drawImage(playerModelAttackLeft, x, y, this);
                x += 15;
            }
        } else if (left && right)
            g.drawImage(playerModelStandRight, x, y, this);
        else if (right)
            g.drawImage(playerModelRight, x, y, this);
        else if (left)
            g.drawImage(playerModelLeft, x, y, this);
        else {
            if (direction == 1)
                g.drawImage(playerModelStandRight, x, y, this);
            if (direction == 0)
                g.drawImage(playerModelStandLeft, x, y, this);
        }
        // g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (attack)
            return;
        if (up && y > 235)
            y -= speed;
        if (down && y < 430)
            y += speed;
        if (left && x > -10)
            x -= speed;
        if (right && x < 750)
            x += speed;
        repaint();
        System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;
            direction = 1;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;
            direction = 0;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            down = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            up = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            attack = true;

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            right = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            left = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            down = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            up = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            attack = false;
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
```

1. This is guaranteed to bring trouble. Don't call the wrong super method inside your override.
2. Don't draw directly in the JFrame but rather in the paintComponent method of a JPanel.
3. Don't override `update` in a Swing program.

**Do** check out the tutorials:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Answer (score 3):

1. You've broken the paint chain, calling `super.paintComponents(g);` from within `paint`.  This will cause no end of weird and wonderful painting issues
2. You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, because they aren't double buffered, but Swing components are, so you really should use a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead.  You should also avoid painting to top level containers like `JFrame` like this, as you it will allow you to paint under the frame borders, never pretty, and `JFrame` has a number of other, overlapping components which reside ontop of it, which could cause issues with when they are repainted (as a child component may not notify it's parent container when it's repainted)
3. You've not "reset" the buffer before painting to it, so you are getting accumulative updates

You "could" add `g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` to your code before you call `paint` in your update method, but as I've already said, you're wasting a lot of time and effort on something that has already been done and provided by the API, if you use it correctly

Take a closer look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for how painting should be done